# how to create tables in RDS Auroramysql using CDK V2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cdk, amazon-aurora

I'm beginner in CDK and I'm trying to create tables when creating RDS Auroramysql instance from my stack in typescript. I didn't find any solutions to this. Is it possible to create  tables when creating RDS instance from CDK?

Answer (score 1):

I created the rds-tools construct for this type of thing. Please give it a try and if you're having issues with it, then please open an Issue on the GitHub page:

https://github.com/mbonig/rds-tools